# HTML editor control for use in MS Access forms

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

Can you suggest a free/bundled HTML editor control for use in MS Access forms? Basically I need to bind a control with a VARCHAR field that allows basic HTML input, formatting and preview functionality -- a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: The version of Access makes a huge difference here, as in Access 2007, the newly-enhanced rich-text control can write HTML directly.

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but here is another:

HTML Editor built around the MS Web Browser control
http://lebans.com/htmleditor.htm

Best of all, it is FREE.

Answer (score 1):

For versions of Access prior to Access 2007, the only one I know of is XStandard at http://xstandard.com/

We tried adding it to a MS Access form for a project about a year ago, it worked well but some things did not work well in the context of our project (french accents, superscript, subscripts).

Answer (score 1):

I too realize this is an old thread and the OP was asking about an HTML editor for 2003.

I just want to add that the so-called "Rich Text" textbox in Access 2007 does indeed using HTML but as near as I can tell it doesn't use proper styling markup (if you want to be able to retrieve the HTML). Here's an example of the code it produces:

```
<div align=center><font size=4><strong>Some Big Bold Text</strong></font></div>
<div align=center><strong>SomeBoldText</strong></div>
<div align=center>Some Regular Text</div>
```